# Why do I add a path to ~/.bash_profile and source it, but there's no effect?

Tags: linux, bash, .bash-profile

In my `install.sh`:

```
# other commands to install java...
echo 'export JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/latest"' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

After this script runs, I type `echo $JAVA_HOME`, but nothing is displayed, but when I execute the `source` command from current shell, JAVA_HOME is displayed when I echo it again.

Why isn't my script working and how do I fix this?

I'm ssh to a fresh CentOS 7 and run the above script.

Answer (score 2):

install.sh runs in a subshell with its own environment. In this environment you set JAVA_HOME successful.

If install.sh with its subshell is finished its environment is gone too. A subshell can't set a variable in its calling process.

If you start install.sh with `source install.sh` it does not run in a subshell and you can set JAVA_HOME. **But** I do not know if the other lines of code in install.sh are prepared to run via `source`.

Comment: But I use `export`, which mean export the variable to global environment, right? So why export does not work?

Comment: With `export` you provide a variable for subprocesses of `install.sh`.

Comment: OK I understand, you explain it well, thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

JAVA_HOME is a environement variable, however, if you leave the  script in which you source `.bash_profile`, it's value will dissapear.

the good new, is that next time you log, value should be set.

Comment: How to make it permanent, as I need JAVA_HOME variable in following scripts?

Comment: have you unlog, log back ? how is $JAVA_HOME ?

Comment: I know that unlog and login again it will work, but as I said I need to use this in the following scripts just after installing java. Thanks for your reply.